# create report and export to pdf programatically in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, report

I need create report (rdlc) and send it through e-mail (c# method).

I've already created the windows service and sending emails.Now i need create a report (rdlc) and i need load it with a model (object) and export to pdf.

I'm not using WinForms... just Windows Service

Apologies for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The rdlc file is created using the Report Designer tool and can be used by either SQL Server Reporting Services or the ReportViewer control, to create the report output.

You're limited to using SSRS, however since the control isn't usable inside a service.

SSRS can be accessed from your service using the ReportExecutionService object. the SSRS server can return a PDF document stream, although you'll need to write it to a file yourself.

If this is a standard report that needs to run on a schedule, you can actually do it all from the SSRS web interface without writing any code.